# Indentation errors in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am doing python programming in notepad++ ,

so as suggested in many posts I have downloaded a tool called "python indent" and set it as enable.

Even after this , when I type in the print statement still I get the indentation errors such as "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level" , any other tool is available for this purpose?
Because in javascript ,when I select the entire file and go to jshint tool and select indentation, I just get the properly indented file .

I am searching for a tool in python , but not able to get it. Anybody has any suggestions please?

edit:

try:

```
    print "hi"
    keys = mgt.get_keys(name)
```

I am getting the error after inserting print statement

Comment: in python indentation belongs to the semantics, so auto-indentation is not possible by design.

Comment: Indentation in Python is like brackets in other programming languages, it cannot be automated. You have to understand the code yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you have mixed tabs and spaces in your block.  Use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: In pep8, it suggests that *Spaces are the preferred indentation method*: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces

Comment: @WKPlus: `space`s are preferred, but `tab`s are still allowed, and mixing them is a really bad idea.  :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to auto-indent python without understanding the code (as @alKid and @Daniel say in the comments):

For example:

```
if(x < y):
    # Since there are no ending brackets
    # how will the program
    # know when you want
# to exit the indentation block?
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely Notepad++ inserting tabs/spaces inconsistent with your existing code.  I first suggest making the spaces/tabs visible; Menu item View / Show Symbol, then select "Show White Space and Tab".  I suggest using this setting for any whitespace-significant language.

I find the default settings in Notepad++ (I'm using v.6.6.7) often mess up my Python indentation.  To correct this: Settings / Preferences / Tab Settings / python; uncheck "use default value" and instead specify "Replace by space."

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime Text 2 there is the option to auto indent using white spaces under View > Indentation > Indent Using Whitespaces. There is also the option to convert indentation to whitespaces or convert indentation to tabs under View > Indentation > Convert Indentation to Tabs.

I know this does not address notepad++ but it is possible notepad++ has something similar available and if not this may be helpful to Sublime Text 2 users.