# Is there a way that I can pass 0 command line arguments in python and have the same result if a particular argument is passed?

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am fairly new to Python.
I need a piece of code to run when either
(i) No command line arguments are passed
(ii) A particular command line argument, say "help", is passed

I have tried working with argparse and sys but I can't seem to get both to work.

For the argparse, I tried "default='help'" while adding the argument:
`parser=add_argument("arg1",default="help")`

For the sys.argv, I tried the following code:

`if (sys.argv[1] == 'help') or not (len(sys.argv) > 1)`

But this just gave me an "Index out of range" error.

Comment: What happens when you fix the indentation error?

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342636/indentation-errors-in-python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979224/indentation-error-in-python

Comment: An indentation error is a python syntax one.  You have even gotten to the point of running the code.  Fix the indentation first (that's basic Python).

Comment: If you are new to Python, don't try to do fancy things with the inputs.  Use straightforward `argparse` arguments.  And make sure you do a `print(args)` to see exactly what the parser has done.

Comment: I forgot to mention this in the question but since I am not passing any arguments in, there is no sys.argv[1]. Hence, I get a `list index out of range` error. Not an indentation error. My bad. I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--arg1", default="help")
args = parser.parse_args()

def help():
    print("I'm here to help, sorta")

if args.arg1 == "help":
    help()
```

Running this without any command line arguments will output the help message.  Running this with `python3 program.py --arg1 help` (assuming this code is in the file program.py) will also output the help message.  Finally, running `python3 program.py --arg1 nohelp` will not output the help message (not just 'nohelp', but anything other than 'help').

Comment: I did try this out. But I still get a `argument '--arg1' required` error.

Comment: I am not getting that error, but rather it runs as expected/described.